# How panoramic images stitching works in AutoGiga Pano & PanoTour Pro applications?

Tags: python, image

I am currently dealing with web-based software that stitches multiple panoramic images together like PanoTour Pro and AutoGiga Pano software do. Can someone please put some lights on how this can be achieved?

Do I need to know SIFT or OpenCV or there is a way to achieve it by general coding?
The software I am dealing with will kind of doing the same thing as PanoTour Pro and AutoGiga Pano do to create 360 tours.

Comment: This seems like a pretty complex task you're taking on here, if you plan to reimplement all the image stitching part! Maybe look for a module that does that for you.

Comment: @AndreiToroplean Okay, so any idea how PanoTour Pro and AutoGiga Pano work? I am kind of trying to do the same. Can you please let me know if it's about just programming that we do for a web application or it's much more critical?

Probably, will not reimplement all the images stitched apart but need to stitch multiple images to create a pano and 360 and need to add audio file to it, hotspots to link another 360/website/image/etc.

Comment: I guess you've seen this:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/17/image-stitching-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: @AndreiToroplean checked OpenCV, never worked on it. However, my application will not stitch real-time images.

Comment: Well, yeah you could achieve that by programming everything from scratch, but you're looking at the ballpark of thousands of lines of code, I'd say. Using image processing modules like the ones you mentioned would give you a head start (and I would say is the only reasonable way to go about solving your problem), but it's still complicated, beyond what I would call web programming, and more into image processing. By doing a quick search on google, I couldn't find a Python package that does that all for you, but maybe I haven't looked enough.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? (if I may ask)

Comment: @AndreiToroplean very helpful. I am actually trying to make something similar to PanoTour Pro and AutoGiga Pano and from scratch.

- I also haven't found a package in Python.

Comment: @AndreiToroplean that's the client scope.